# Calling $http inside angularjs watch from a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-promise

I am trying to call $http service from inside a watch in my directive. Assuming, the directive is put on more than one input element. If the value of all elements changes together, the watches fire back to back and $http gets called back to back as well, sometimes messing up the response for each $http call, i.e for consecutive $http calls, even though the inputs are different response comes the same. What is the proper way to structure the code for this case? Can i use promise to resolve this. If yes, then how, considering this is the same $http call, being called with different inputs.

```
 Utils.directive('setDescription', function ($q,$http,$timeout) {
                var directive = {};
                directive.priority = 1;
                directive.restrict = 'A'; 
                directive.require = 'ngModel';
                directive.link = function(scope,element,attributes,ngModel) {
                    scope.isInput = false;
                    scope.getDescription = true;
                    scope.elementArray = [];
                    element.bind("keypress", function (event) {
                       scope.isInput = true;
                       return true; 
                    });

                    scope.$watch(function(){
                        var codeElem = element.next();
                        if(codeElem[0]!=undefined){
                            codeElem=codeElem[0];
                        }
                        return scope.gettheObject(codeElem.name,scope);
                    },function(newValue,oldValue){
                        if(!scope.isInput && scope.getDescription){
                          if(newValue!=undefined && (newValue.trim())!=""){
                            $timeout(function() {
                                element.val(newValue);       
                                scope.elementArray.push(element);
                                $http({
                                    method: 'POST', 
                                    url: Constants.BASE_REST_URL + '/picklist/pickListResultGeneric',                   
                                    data : CryptoHelperService.getEncryptedData(searchstr,true),
                                    headers: CryptoHelperService.getEncryptionHeaders(),
                                    cache: false,
                                    xsrfCookieName : 'nicAccessCookie'
                                }).then(function(response) {
                                    response.data = CryptoHelperService.getDecryptedResponse(response.data,response.headers);
                                });
                            });
                          }
                        }   
                    });
                }
                return directive;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the help of promises. Using `$q.when()` (which is same as `$q.resolve()`), creates a promise which is immediately resolved with the given value. For each element in the array, the `$http` call is constructed and added in the promise chain. Once all the elements are iterated over, each call is invoked in the same order in which they were added in the chain.

```
 var promiseChain = $q.when();
    scope.elementArray.forEach(function(elem) {
          //Initiate a chain of promises for each REST call
           promiseChain = promiseChain.then(function() {
             return $http({
                            method: 'POST', 
                            url: someURL,       
                            data : someData
                        });
           });  
           //Each promise in the chain is then resolved individually in the order in which they were invoked.
           promiseChain.then(function(response) {
                //do stuff here after each call returns individually                
           });                      
    });
```